# New site column not displaying in SPF2010

Tags: sharepoint, sharepointfoundation2010

After much trials-and-errors, I've managed to find how to add new columns in Site Pages of our Sharepoint Foundation 2010.

I'll explain using a field called "Category" I created. The problem I have now is that the only way to add or edit my page categories is to first create a new page, enter its title when asked by the pop-up, enter the content of the page, saving, and then going back in to the page properties. That's the only place I'm seeing my new "category" field.

I've set the field as "required", so it's supposed to be filled, but it doesn't seem to matter.

Moreso, I'd like to see the categories of the page I'm looking at at the bottom, for example, but when I open a page I only see its title and content, nothing else.

Can someone help me understand how to manage this? I'm mostly on my own and SPF2010 is not very well documented for a newbie from what I've seen in my searches.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Is your new column called Category part of your default View or whatever View that you are looking at?

Answer (score 0):

Your question reminds me a precision I didn't wrote about:

In the "All Pages" View (if I understand Sharepoint correctly), which is like a list of all the pages of my site, I've managed to add columns for the new fields I've created.

My wish is to be able to enter data for these new fields at page creation, like when we enter the title of a new page, and/or when I go to edit its content.

Only place so far I found to edit my new fields is in the Page Properties, which requires the page to be created first, or in this "All Pages" View where I added my fields. I'd like to categorize my pages as I create them, which could save us lots of time since we're starting our documentation project and nothing has been done yet...